# JavaScript function outputing page's DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I need to write a js function that outputs a DOM-tree by button click. The tree should be output as an unnumbered list (ul) with attachments and it's needed to use the name of the element, i.e. head, body, p, div, etc., and the element id as the text output in the list item (of course if it is specified). I thought it would work but there are some "undefined" elements but they shouldn't be here. So I don't understand what's wrong

```js
function DOM_Tree(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.body.childNodes.length - 1; i++) {
    if (document.body.childNodes[i].id != 'tree') {
      let ul = document.getElementById('tree');
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      let el = document.body.childNodes[i];
      let ul1 = document.createElement('ul');
      if (el.hasChildNodes()) {
        li.innerText = document.body.childNodes[i].id;
        ul.append(li);
        for (let j = 0; j < el.childNodes.length; j++) {
          if (el.childNodes[j].id != undefined) {
            let li1 = document.createElement('li');
            li1.innerText = el.childNodes[j].id;
            ul1.append(li1);
          }
          let li1 = document.createElement('li');
          li1.innerText = el.childNodes[j].id;
          ul1.append(li1);
        }
        ul.append(ul1);
      } else {
        if (document.body.childNodes[i].id != undefined) {
          li.innerText = document.body.childNodes[i].id;
          ul.append(li);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
confirmButton.onclick = function() {
  DOM_Tree(document.body);
  alert('click');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container1" style="background-color: cyan;">
    <h1 id="header1">Header</h1>
    <p id="paragraph1">Paragraph</p>
    <div id="container2" style="background-color: red;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="tree"></ul>
  <input type="text" id="formText">
  <br>
  <button id="confirmButton" style="margin-top: 5px;">Build a DOM tree</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your function isn't recursive; it can't possibly work for an arbitrarily deep DOM tree. Furthermore, it'd probably be a good idea to compute the new "representative" tree into memory and only then splat it into the DOM.

Comment: @AKX could you please help me how to do it?

Comment: You have `li1.innerText = el.childNodes[j].id;` outside the `if` that checks whether this is undefined.

Comment: Why do you do that twice? The first one is inside the `if`, the second one is after.

Comment: @Barmar oh sorry, I forgot to comment it

Answer (score -1):

You have this block of code twice:

```
          let li1 = document.createElement('li');
          li1.innerText = el.childNodes[j].id;
          ul1.append(li1);
```

The first one is inside an `if (el.childNodes[j].id != undefined)`, so it won't print undefined IDs. The second one is after the `if`, so it prints the undefined IDs.

Just removing the second block gets rid of `undefined` bullets.

If you want the input to specify the ID to start from, use `document.getElementById()` in the `onclick` function. Then change `DOM_Tree` to use `e` instead of `document.body` as its starting element.

```js
function DOM_Tree(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < e.childNodes.length - 1; i++) {
    if (e.childNodes[i].id != 'tree') {
      let ul = document.getElementById('tree');
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      let el = e.childNodes[i];
      let ul1 = document.createElement('ul');
      if (el.hasChildNodes()) {
        li.innerText = e.childNodes[i].id;
        ul.append(li);
        for (let j = 0; j < el.childNodes.length; j++) {
          if (el.childNodes[j].id != undefined) {
            let li1 = document.createElement('li');
            li1.innerText = el.childNodes[j].id;
            ul1.append(li1);
          }
        }
        ul.append(ul1);
      } else {
        if (e.childNodes[i].id != undefined) {
          li.innerText = e.childNodes[i].id;
          ul.append(li);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
confirmButton.onclick = function() {
  let target = document.body; // default target
  let id = document.getElementById("formText").value;
  if (id) {
    target = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!target) {
      alert(`ID ${id} not found`);
      return;
    }
  }
  DOM_Tree(target);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container1" style="background-color: cyan;">
    <h1 id="header1">Header</h1>
    <p id="paragraph1">Paragraph</p>
    <div id="container2" style="background-color: red;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="tree"></ul>
  <input type="text" id="formText" placeholder="ID to start at, default = document.body">
  <br>
  <button id="confirmButton" style="margin-top: 5px;">Build a DOM tree</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! Also could you help to link it with button? I mean the function should called on the page when the button is clicked and the element starting from which to display the tree is indicated by its id, which is entered in the text field.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pair of recursive functions that first builds a description of the tree as plain objects, then renders that description out into a DOM tree of UL/LI.

```js
function describeNode(node) {
  return {
    id: node.id,
    type: node.nodeType,
    text: node.textContent,
    children: [...node.childNodes].map(describeNode),
  };
}

function renderDescription(d) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  if (d.type === 3) { // Text node with content
    if (!d.text.trim().length) {
      return null; // Empty node, don't represent
    }
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`text: ` + d.text));
  } else {
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`node of type ${d.type}, id ${d.id || '--'}`));
  }
  if (d.children && d.children.length) {
    const childrenUl = document.createElement("ul");
    li.appendChild(childrenUl);
    d.children.map(renderDescription).forEach((c) => c && childrenUl.appendChild(c));
  }
  return li;
}

const descr = describeNode(document.getElementById("source"));
document.getElementById("result_json").value = JSON.stringify(descr, null, 2);
document.getElementById("result_tree").appendChild(renderDescription(descr));
```

```html
<main id="source">
  <div id="container1" style="background-color: cyan;">
    <h1 id="header1">Header</h1>
    <p id="paragraph1">Paragraph</p>
    <div id="container2" style="background-color: red;">
      <h2 id="header2">SubHeader</h1>
        <p id="paragraph2">Sub-Paragraph</p>
        <p id="paragraph3">Sub-Paragraph Two</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<textarea id="result_json"></textarea>
<ul id="result_tree"></ul>
```